# How to catch when screen orientation change in react native with mobx?

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobx, screen-orientation

Can you explain me the right way to handle orientation changing in react native app with mobX.
For now I have tried make something like this:

```
@observer
export class ChartSTMWork extends Component {
  currwidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
  render() {
    this.currwidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
    return();
  }
}
```

But this code change the currWidth only if render call. And in situation when I have already rendered table and change orientation of smartphone after this render, there is no effect to currWidth variable.

Or maybe I need to use some small timer to check Dimensions.get("window").width and make currWidth observable?

```
 @observer
    export class ChartSTMWork extends Component {
      @observable currwidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
      someTimerEvery200ms(){
         currwidth = Dimensions.get("window").width
      }
 }
```

But this solution is looks like dirty solution.

How I need to handle this in right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve by this solution. Maybe it's will be heplful for someone

```
  eventToDemension = Dimensions.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    this.currwidth = e.window.width;
  });
  @observable currwidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
```